# add_query_arg() One Key with multiple values

Tags: urls

## The Goal

I am wanting to use add_query_arg() like so:

```
$url = add_query_arg(array(
    'count'    => '100',
    'property' => array(
        'abc',
        'xyz'
    )
), $base_url );
```

The api I am using requires me to repeat the property key in my api call

```
http://api-call.com/?count=100&property=abc&property=xyz
```

## The Problem

WordPress is outputting the code below because it is an array.

```
http://api-call.com/?count=100&property[0]=abc&property[1]=xyz
```

I have tried this workaround:

```
$url = add_query_arg(array(
    'count'    => '100',
    'property' => 'abc',
    'property' => 'xyz'
), $base_url );
```

but WordPress outputs only the last property value

```
http://api-call.com/?count=100&property=xyz
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You have to do a search and replace on $url like the following -

```
$url = add_query_arg( array(
    'count'    => '100',
    'property' => array(
        'abc',
        'xyz'
    )
), $base_url );

// following line will remove [*] and * can be nothing or 0-9
$api_url = preg_replace( '/\[\d*\]/', '', $url );

// Output will be like the following
// http://api-call.com/?count=100&property=abc&property=xyz
```

Comment: Hey @obiPlabon, I have 13 properties. Would this replace 10, 11, 12 with nothing?

Comment: It'll replace these patterns `[] and [n]`. Where `n` can be 0 to any number, e.g 10, 11, 12, 100, 200, 9999999. I said nothing or 0-9, not 10, 12 with nothing.

Comment: There isn't a smarter built-in solution for this? using regex is plainly not a nice solution but rather a hack - you can use it everywhere - but should you?